# Mark an option as selected from dynamic list of options

Tags: php, html

I've used `Selected="Selected"` on `SELECT` that is fed by values I have written into the code, my query is how can I use it with a dynamic query from the MySQL db?

This is my written code

```
<label>Fuel</label>
<select tabindex="1" id="proptenure" name="proptenure">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1" <?php echo ($searchfuel == '1' ? 'selected' : '')?>>Mains gas</option>
<option value="2" <?php echo ($searchfuel == '2' ? 'selected' : '')?>>Wood or coal fire</option>
<option value="3" <?php echo ($searchfuel == '3' ? 'selected' : '')?>>Oil</option>
<option value="4" <?php echo ($searchfuel == '4' ? 'selected' : '')?>>Electric storage heaters</option>
<option value="5" <?php echo ($searchfuel == '5' ? 'selected' : '')?>>LPG or bottled gas</option>
<option value="6" <?php echo ($searchfuel == '6' ? 'selected' : '')?>>No central heating system</option>
</select>
```

How can use the above type of line on my Query based `SELECT`

```
<?php echo ($searchtenure == '2' ? 'selected' : '')?>
```

This is an example of how I'm using `SELECT` from a query

```
<label>Fuel Type</label> 
<?php $fueltype = db::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM lkup_fueltype'); 
if(!$fueltype->count()) { 
    echo 'Problem'; 
} else { ?> 
<select tabindex="1" id="propertyfueltype" name="propertyfueltype"> 
<?php foreach ($fueltype->results() as $fueltype) { ?> 
<option value="<?php echo $fueltype->PropertyFuelType; ?>"><?php echo $fueltype->PropertyFuelType; ?></option> <?php } } ?> 
</select>
```

So how can I use the Selected="selected"?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
<label>Fuel Type</label> 
<?php $fueltype = db::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM lkup_fueltype'); 
if(!$fueltype->count()) { 
    echo 'Problem'; 
} else { ?> 
<select tabindex="1" id="propertyfueltype" name="propertyfueltype"> 
<?php foreach ($fueltype->results() as $fueltype) { ?> 
<?php if($fueltype->PropertyFuelType == 2){ $selected = ' selected="selected"'; }else{ $selected = NULL; }?>
<option value="<?php echo $fueltype->PropertyFuelType; ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $fueltype->PropertyFuelType; ?></option> <?php } } ?> 
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed my original example as it wasn't a true reflection of both examples. On your line `<?php if($fueltype->PropertyFuelType == 2){ $selected = ' selected="selected"'; }else{ $selected = NULL; }?>` how would you use it if there were more than 2 options?

Comment: `<?php if(($fueltype->PropertyFuelType == 2) || ($fueltype->PropertyFuelType == 3)){ $selected = ' selected="selected"'; }else{ $selected = NULL; } ?>`

Comment: Thanks, and would it be need to do this for each number if options in the SELECT? What if there were a hundred options to choose, how would the selected='selected' work then?

Comment: I ask this as on one of my forms there is a SELECT with over a 100 options & if I was to pre populate that from with as an edit record I would want to see what's already been input previously

Comment: What would happen if the list populating the `SELECT` was say a 100 options, how would the selected="selected" work then?